# filter dataframe using zipped list

Tags: python, pandas

I have  a dataframe which includes two data frame columns with a min_peak and a max_peak value. 
I am attempting to filter the index('Date') values which are timestamps between the two peaks.
I would like to allocate a value of 0 for all dates that are greater than the min_peak but less than the max_peak and a value of 1 if false.

```
Date
2019-02-02    0.3985
2019-09-24    1.4612
2019-12-18    1.5996
2020-03-12    0.0001
Name: min_peak, dtype: float64
Date
2019-07-03    3.4769
2019-11-14    2.9666
2020-03-05    4.6239
2020-06-09    4.3605
Name: max_peak, dtype: float64
```

I have a list of the zipped dates for the min_peak and max_peak columns but am not sure how to filter my dataframe using the values.

```
[(Timestamp('2019-02-02 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2019-07-03 00:00:00')), (Timestamp('2019-09-24 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2019-11-14 00:00:00')), (Timestamp('2019-12-18 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2020-03-05 00:00:00')), (Timestamp('2020-03-12 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2020-06-09 00:00:00'))]
```

As an example I would filter my dataframe based on the first two peaks `'2019-02-02 00:00:00'` and `2019-07-03 00:00:00` , for all index values greater than `2019-02-02 00:00:00` but less than '`2019-07-03 00:00:00` to equal 0.

For all values after `'2019-07-03 00:00:00'` but less than `2019-09-24 00:00:00'` to equal 1.

I have looked tried using the `loc` method and the `df.index.isin` but without success.

Comment: Is there a reason you'd like to filter using the timestamp instead of setting values greater than max, less than min as 0 based on the peak value?

Comment: I though this would be the easiest way as the values going from the minpeak to maxpeak would be different to the values from maxpeak to the next minpeak. Also the info gets updated weekly and the minpeak/maxpeak may be recalculated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC you want to set a new colum (`flag` in my example) to `1` if the index (`Date`) is within any of the tuples from the list. You can use an [`IntervalIndex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.IntervalIndex.html) and [`get_indexer`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_indexer.html) which will return the index position (`>= 0`) in the intervall index or `-1` if the date isn't in any intervall of the index.

Example:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import Timestamp

#make sample data
df = pd.DataFrame(index=pd.date_range('2019-01-01', '2020-06-15', freq='W'))
df['flag'] = 0

#make IntervalIndex
l = [(Timestamp('2019-02-02 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2019-07-03 00:00:00')), (Timestamp('2019-09-24 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2019-11-14 00:00:00')), (Timestamp('2019-12-18 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2020-03-05 00:00:00')), (Timestamp('2020-03-12 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2020-06-09 00:00:00'))]
idx = pd.IntervalIndex.from_tuples(l)


#set flag to 1 for all index values within given intervals
df.loc[idx.get_indexer(df.index)>=0, 'flag'] = 1
```